# how to plot a column of arrays where i need to count how many times a different values come up in all these arrays

Tags: python, database, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm working with a data base of shows and I'm wanting to plot on a bar graph how many times each genre is used over all the shows so I can show the most popular genres. The issue I'm having is that a show (a show is a row in the database) usually has more then 1 genre (for example: `['Comedy', 'Drama','Sci-Fi']` might be the genres of 1 show). I'd like to displays genres on their own (I'm using jupyter with the pandas, matplotlib,...).
This is the code I've made so far:

```
bar_data = content2['genre'].value_counts().sort_values().tail(20)
bar_plot = bar_data.plot.barh(figsize=(20, 12))
bar_plot.set_title("genre poplularity")
bar_plot.set_xlabel("amount of times genre is used")
bar_plot.set_ylabel("genres")
plt.show()
```

Some ways that I've tried to solve this by trying to split at the `','` but this  doesn't work (probably because it's not a string).
So could anyone help me figure out how to plot a column of arrays like this.

end result should be something like this but then in a bar graph

```
Comedy: 800
Adventure: 756
Sci-Fi: 698
Kids: 630
```

Thank you very much for you time and help

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have each genre as a list, you can use `explode()` to get the individual strings from it. Then use `value_counts()`.

```
content2['genre'].explode().value_counts()
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

It looks like each row is a string. So you will first have to strip (`strip('[]')`) the '[]', then split the string by commas (`split(',')`) to get the genre names. This can be done using the following code snippet.

```
content2['genre'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this doesn't seem to change anything. before i get some values with only 1 genre but then also those with more then 1 values. if you would want to see the output that i get here is a print screen of it http://prntscr.com/teije0

Comment: how would you like me to show you it's kinda big to put on a print screen and content2 is a version of a database that i've added in extra columns (not genre) and so sending the database isnt really going to help that much

Comment: if you want here is a print screen of the genre column http://prntscr.com/teiohr

Comment: I have tested the code in a similar column, it works fine. Have you done any other pre-processing on the column? Here's my screenshot: https://imgur.com/jlJeWzD

Comment: no the only changes i've done are dropping rows with empty values, adding new columns and none of those had anything to do with that column

Comment: i can send you a we transfer link of the original data base the only difference should be that you have more data since i've removed some rows and mine has some extra columns

Comment: Sure, I can have a look at it. You can send me 10/20 rows, that way it would be faster.

Comment: if you want to try it for yourself here is the link to the data base https://wetransfer.com/downloads/df347019c2d25fa7eb4d77d29f4d51cd20200709065714/ca4200

Comment: As suspected, you have the genre column as a string! Please note that in the question. I am updating the answer.

Comment: this works, when i was trying to do it for myself i thought it might have been a string but i didnt know how to check for sure or how to fix it but  anyways thank you so much you've been a great help <3

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!

Comment: maybe a little fyi i ended up having to split on ', ' and not ',' (a space aswell) since i would've otherwise had genres with a space infront of it making it not count as 1 but as 2 different types of genres